# Uploading and reading of files from the root directory in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to verify the ownership of my website by placing a specific file in the root directory. How can I do this in asp.net mvc ? What I'm trying to achieve is the URL:

```
http://somehost/MyWebsite/OwnershipFile.txt
```

I have tried creating an Action in the Home Controller but that doesn't work because the link contains the suffix .txt.

If my understanding is correct, asp.net mvc's razor is an extension-less view engine. That being the case, how can I achieve what I'm after ?

Comment: Do you have to put a file name (with .txt) in the url? or can you also use http://somehost/MyWebsite/OwnershipFile ? if so, all you'll have to do is a regular get action... another question - does the file name changes? or it's just a single file/action we are talking about?

Comment: Yes, i have to pur a filename with .txt in the URL ... that's where i am stuck